# Cocoa methods are not called at all when using "do not embed" for library

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have spent an awful amount of time on that problem (I am not very good at Objective-C I must admit) without success so I need your expertise.

I am developing several plugins, which are just shared libraries in this case. One of them declares Cocoa classes for the others to use and I manage to have it loading first.

For the other plugin, I chose to "do not embed" the library but to make it "required" in linking (in Xcode).

**The problem:**

In the **other** plugin, I try to use a class, let's call it `myArray`.

I can get the `objc_class` for it (with `objc_getClass`), I can also get the library's path with `class_getImageName`, so everything tells me that the library is loaded and active. **However**, when I use any method like

```objc
[myArray doSomethingWith:...];
```

no method is ever called and all calls return 0. No error. No exception.

I don't get how that can happen.

Can someone help me, please ?

And thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that in this case [myArray doSomethingWith:...]; myArray object is not nil?

Comment: Well I use first id myClass = objc_getClass( "myClass" ), which is not nil, and then I use var1 = [myClass doSomethingWith:...] (myClass as a literal).

Comment: ??? What type is `myClass`? You've marked it here as `id`. Is it really `Class`? Is `doSomethingWith:` an instance method or a class method? (If "nothing happens", it is very, very likely that `myClass` is nil. You really want to be 100% certain that this is not true, because that's almost always the cause of "nothing happens.") You likely need to edit this question to post some real code (ideally a minimal, reproducible example, but at as minimum real code with precisely what is true at each line). I suspect you're not doing what you think you're doing.